# DLookUp not working properly in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, dlookup

Trying to pull the value in the Query to populate Form Field, not working with what I've tried.

Table 1: Quote Data

Fields: Quote #, Part #, CNC Hours

Table 2: Rate Chart

Fields: Rate Type, Cost ($)

Query 1: Cost of CNC

Fields: Quote #, Part #, CNC Hours, Parts Per Mag, Rate Type (Criteria: "3D Shop"), Cost ($)

Expression: Cost of CNC= [CNC Hours]*[Cost ($)]/[Parts Per Mag]

Main Form: Generate Quotes

SubForm: Quote Data Subform

Field Box: CNC $

Control Source: =DLookUp("[Cost of CNC]", "[Cost of CNC]", "[Part #]=" & [Forms]![Cost of CNC Subform]![Part #])

With the above Control Source I keep getting #Name? in the field text box CNC $.

I've also tried:

=DLookUp("[Cost of CNC]", "[Cost of CNC]", "[Part #] = " & [Part #]) but I get #Error.

What am I doing wrong?

I want the value in Cost of CNC (associated with the proper Part #) to populate Form Field: CNC $.

Comment: Field and table are both named "Cost of CNC"? Advise not to use space in naming convention, nor punctuation/special characters (underscore is only exception). Better would be QuoteNum, PartNum, CNC_Dol.

Comment: Is [Part #] a text field? If so, need apostrophe delimiters. `"[Part #]='" & [Part #] & "'")`. Do you have a combobox for selection of part? A better approach is to include cost as column of combobox then reference that column to display in a textbox: `=cbxPart.Column(2)`.

Comment: Don't give query and field the same name, this will confuse Access or you or both.

Comment: Query is named: Cost of CNC; column in the Query is name: Cost of CNC. All my tables and forms are named with spaces, and I have not had a problem in 3 years of running my system.   [Part #] is a field within my subform and pulls from Quote Data table.  It is not a combo box as the Subform populates based on the Quote # associated to the Main Form: Generate Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work:

```
=DLookUp("[Cost of CNC]", "[Cost of CNC]", "[Part #]='"&[Part #]& "'")
```